# Where is stored a gl.CreateTexture?

Tags: memory, webgl, textures

When [creating a new texture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/createTexture) using `createTexture` from the Web `GL` context, where is it stored? And it uses purely the GPU?

In the memory or in the graphics card memory? How's the performance in terms of resources (specially CPU load)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gl.createTexture` provides you with a GPU resource id, when and if that texture is allocated in GPU memory is up to the GPU driver.